# Formatting a line in a comment using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, comments, currency

I'm struggling to find a way to format a line that in a comment that is required to be a currency value.

I've set the variable as currency, but it reverts back to basic when used in a comment.

```
Dim wage As Currency
wage = Range("b14")

Range("C14") = wage

Range("D14").AddComment
Range("D14").Comment.Visible = False
Range("D14").Comment.Text Text:=
 Application.UserName & Chr(10) & wage & Chr(10) & "Joe Bloggs"
```

When i hover the wage variable in break mode is showing the value in b14 as plain, however i require it to appear as currency (£#.##)

The following syntax appears when i start writing

Text([Text], [Start], [Overwrite]) as string

I'm not sure, but could the overwrite section be the key???

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Text:=Application.UserName & Chr(10) & format(wage, "£#,##0.00") & Chr(10) & "Joe Bloggs"`

Comment: Thanks @cyboashu your suggestion worked brilliantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cell **B14** has already been formatted to the proper currency format, then replace:

```
Dim wage As Currency
wage = Range("b14")
```

with:

```
Dim wage as String
wage = Range("B14").Text
```